# How can I print the second row value in the first row column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have fetching data as follows:

```
start_date       end_date      amount   
12/10/2020          -          1800000
12/18/2020          -          1200000
01/18/2021          -          1000000
```

I would like to print the start date of the second row to the end date of the first row for X rows I am fetching so that the table becomes as follows:

```
start_date       end_date      amount   
12/10/2020      12/18/2020     1800000
12/18/2020      01/18/2021     1200000
01/18/2021          -          1000000
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Have a look at `LAG`/`LEAD`.

Comment: it works perfectly! I've solved it with a LAG function and an over clause! Thanks a bunch man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEAD` as follows:

```
select start_Date,
       lead(start_date) over (order by start_Date) as end_Date
       amount
  from your_Table t
```

Comment: When doing this, the order end_date is not fetched properly, it is done as follows:

start_date       end_date      amount   
12/10/2020      12/18/2020     1800000
12/18/2020           -                1200000
01/18/2021      12/10/2020     1000000

It is done in the wrong way for the second and third rows, only right for the first one..

Comment: Is start_Date a date?

Comment: Fixed when using a real date instead of an nvarchar converted one. Thanks for the tip!!

Answer (score 1):

Use lead, if you have no column for partition by, use only order by in the over()

```
   select start_date, 
           lead(start_date) over (partition by ... order by start_date) as end_date, 
           amount
   ...
```

Comment: When doing this, the order end_date is not fetched properly, it is done as follows:

start_date       end_date      amount   
12/10/2020      12/18/2020     1800000
12/18/2020           -                1200000
01/18/2021      12/10/2020     1000000

It is done in the wrong way for the second and third rows, only right for the first one..

Comment: same problem, the dates are pulled up in the wrong way

Comment: Fixed when using a real date instead of an nvarchar converted one.

Answer (score 1):

Used the sample table and selected the data. Please change the SQL query as per your need.

```
DECLARE @Range TABLE (
    start_date DATETIME
    ,end_date DATETIME
    ,amount INT
    )

INSERT @Range
SELECT '12/10/2020'
    ,NULL
    ,1800000

UNION ALL

SELECT '12/18/2020'
    ,NULL
    ,1200000

UNION ALL

SELECT '01/18/2021'
    ,NULL
    ,1000000

SELECT start_date
    ,LEAD(start_date, 1) OVER (
        ORDER BY start_date
        ) AS end_date
    ,amount
FROM @Range;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option for **LEAD** by using **Recursive CTE**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(start_date   DATE,    end_date   DATE,     amount   INT)

Insert into @T VALUES
('12/10/2020',NULL,1800000),
('12/18/2020',NULL,1200000),
('01/18/2021',NULL,1000000)

;WITH CTE AS(
                   SELECT rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY End_Date),amount,Start_Date,End_Date
                   FROM @T
                 )
               SELECT
               CTE.start_date,CTE.amount,Nex.start_date AS[End Date]
               FROM CTE
               LEFT JOIN CTE prev ON prev.rownum = CTE.rownum - 1
               LEFT JOIN CTE nex ON nex.rownum = CTE.rownum + 1
```